# Vagrant won't run when setting up Homestead

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I went through all the steps from [this manual of how to setup Homestead.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)
I've got a problem, when I try to run the vagrant box:

```
mysystem@me:~/Google Drive/Homestead$ vagrant up
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The home directory you specified is not accessible. The home
directory that Vagrant uses must be both readable and writable.

You specified: /home/mysystem/.vagrant.d
```

I tried putting the Homestead folder in different places of the system. The Google Drive folder is readable/writable - I create files/folders there without the sudo command. Maybe I am not trying to fix the correct thing, I don't know.
This is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
authorize: ~/Google\ Drive/Homestead/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/Google\ Drive/Homestead/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Google\ Drive/Homestead/workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

and the SSH key file that I generated is `~/Google\ Drive/Homestead/homestead_key.pub`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, for those who might have the same problem, here's the solution and explanation for it:

Running the command `whoami; ls -dlah ~/.vagrant.d/` showed me `drwxr-xr-x 7 root root` result indicating that the vagrant folder is owned by root, which was causing the problem of it being not accessible.

The command `sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername ~/.vagrant.d` will fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms specified above but with a different solution.  I had set the environment variable "VAGRANT_HOME" to something I used in the script.  This caused vagrant to look in the director I specified instead of its true home directory.  Once I changed my environment variable to something else all was fine.